# Setting Rhino optimization in Ant

Tags: javascript, ant

I have an ant task which runs the Rihno shell java program. I want to provide an optimization level level 0 as per [Rihno documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Shell)

```
         <java classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main" failonerror="true">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${requirejs.dir}/build/lib/rhino/js.jar" />
                <pathelement location="${requirejs.dir}/build/lib/closure/compiler.jar" />
            </classpath>
            <arg value="${requirejs.dir}/r.js"/>
            <arg value="-o"/>
            <arg value="@{build}"/>
        </java>
```

I am not sure how to set the arg value, I think it should have been something like `<arg value="-o 0"/>` but its not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Rhino shell documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Shell), the optimization option is either `-O optLevel` (that's an *uppercase* "oh") or `-opt optLevel`. So the Ant task becomes...

```
 <java classname="org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main" failonerror="true">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${requirejs.dir}/build/lib/rhino/js.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${requirejs.dir}/build/lib/closure/compiler.jar" />
    </classpath>
    <arg value="${requirejs.dir}/r.js"/>
    <arg value="-opt"/>
    <arg value="0"/>
    <arg value="@{build}"/>
</java>
```

Notice that the option name and the option value go into two separate `<arg value="...">` elements.